# SQL: query two time periods with relevant matching data only

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please forgive the title of this question, but I can't think of concise way of asking the below.

In a nutshell, I have about 400 stores whose transactions I want to compare now and the same time last year. The problem is that last year, some stores weren't around or had no data and vice-versa. I want to write a query that compares now and then only where I have store data in both time periods.

Consider this data:

```
storeID   tranDate     qty  sale
A         2013-12-01     1   $10
B         2013-12-02     1   $10
C         2013-12-03     1   $10
D         2013-12-04     1   $10
A         2012-12-05     1   $10
A         2012-12-09     1   $10
D         2012-12-06     1   $10
E         2012-12-07     1   $10
F         2012-12-08     1   $10
```

To query December data, I would do something like:

```
select * 
from myTable
where (tranDate between @DateStart and @DateEnd) or (tranDate between @DateStartPreviousYear and @DateEndPreviousYear)
```

But if I wanted to query December like-for-like (i.e. Stores A and D are the only common to stores to both now and last year), how would I do this?

In my real world, I will have about 2 million transactions per month over about 400 stores.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for your answers so far. I have edited my sample data to include two records for store A in December 2012 - am I right in saying that this causes a problem for joining on StoreID

Comment: In your example, do you just want a list of all transactions for store a and d?

Comment: I misread your question, I have corrected my response.

Comment: make it very clear that what is last year.what parameter(sample) you will pass.last year mean dec-2013 and jan-2012 is this correct.you may compare if data are in consecutive years. like from 2010 to 2013.
so previous years mean what in terms f years and exact month.doi say datediff should be 1 year ?

Answer (score 0):

do a join for each date range like such:

```
SELECT A.qty + B.qty AS [Qty],
   A.sale + B.sale AS [Sales],
   A.StoreID
FROM myTable  AS A
JOIN myTable AS B
  ON B.StoreId = A.StoreId
WHERE  A.trandate between @monthstart and @monthend
  AND  B.trandate between @MonthStartPrevious and @MonthEndPrevious
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  MyTable
INNER JOIN MyTable
       AS PreviousYear
       ON PreviousYear.StoreID = MyTable.StoreID
       AND PreviousYear.tranDate Between @PreviousMonthSTart AND @PreviousMonthEnd
WHERE TranDate Between @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

read my comment properly.i am not using any parameter as parameter data is not clear to me.
you must mention for which sample data it won't work.

```
Declare @Store table (storeID char(1),tranDate date,qty int, sale money)
insert into @Store values('A','2013-12-01',1,$10),('B','2013-12-02',1,   $10),('C','2013-12-03',1,$10),('D','2013-12-04',1,$10)
,('A','2012-12-05',1,$10),('D','2012-12-06',1,$10),('E','2012-12-07',1,$10),('F','2012-12-08',1,$10)

;with CTE as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by storeID order by tranDate)rn   from @Store)

select * from cte a
inner join cte b on a.storeID=b.storeID and( b.rn-a.rn)=1
and datediff(year,a.tranDate,b.tranDate)=1
```